# Highcharts: yAxis duration in hours resets every 24h

Tags: highcharts

[image]

The image speaks by itself, I want to display a duration in **hours** on the yAxis. but everytime the value reaches 24h, the yAxis resets to 0. the actual value of the blue bar in the image is 28:19:15 but it shows only 4 hours because it has been resetted (4th value of yAxis shows 0)

my current config:

```
{
"chart": {
    "type": "column"
},
"plotOptions": {
    "column": {
        "dataLabels": {
            "enabled": true
        }
    }
},
"series": [
    {
        "data": [
            101955467,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "dataLabels": {
            "enabled": true,
            "format": "{y:%H:%M:%S}"
        },
        "name": "duration",
        "stack": null,
        "yAxis": "1"
    }
],
"xAxis": [
    {
        "categories": [
            "cat 1",
            "cat 2",
            "cat 3"
        ]
    }
],
"yAxis": [
    {
        "allow_decimals": false,
        "dateTimeLabelFormats": {
            "day": "%H:%M",
            "hour": "%H:%M",
            "minute": "%H:%M",
            "month": "%H:%M",
            "second": "%H:%M",
            "week": "%H:%M",
            "year": "%H:%M"
        },
        "id": "1",
        "labels": {
            "format": "{value:%H:%M:%S}"
        },
        "max": 101955467,
        "min": 0,
        "opposite": false,
        "title": {
            "text": "duration"
        },
        "type": "datetime"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you want to get a total time instead of DateTime. In this case, you'll need to create your own label formatter that will convert milliseconds to a number of hours, minutes and seconds.

Example code:

```
  dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          let s, m, h;
          s = this.y / 1000;
          h = parseInt(s / 3600);
          s = s % 3600;
          m = parseInt(s / 60);
          s = (s % 60).toFixed(0);
          let number = (h + ":" + m + ":" + s);

          return number;
        }
      }
```

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels.formatter

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lcjewr2o/

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing something very similar to this. I'm pretty disapointed because i didn't want to use custom callbacks.
Thanks anyways